# How do I change the Facebook Redirect URL in an MVC5 webapp?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5

I've deployed my MVC5 application onto a server (was on localhost up until now), and now the Facebook authentication isn't working, because the redirect URL is still set to localhost. The link generated starts with:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsignin-facebook

How does it generate the redirect_uri? I need to specify my new server's address and thought it would be by changing the IISUrl property in the project's csproj file, but when I do, the project fails to load.

I've whitelisted the new URL at the Facebook side, I just can't work out how to tell my application itself that it has relocated (I'm guessing it's generating the value for the redirect_url parameter based on a value/setting somewhere in my application).

I'm using the Microsoft Owin packages, and the code to generate the button is:

```
@foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-social btn-@p.AuthenticationType.ToLower()" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">
                            @p.AuthenticationType
          <i class="fa fa-@p.AuthenticationType.ToLower()"></i>
    </button>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you check in `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs `?

Comment: I did, but couldn't see anything. There's a bit about facebook where I mention my appID and secret, but nothing about the path. Is it something to do with this line: LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")?

Comment: You can override from there, but the default is `/signin-facebook` and the owin pipeline prepends the base uri from the request. You're sure the server you have deployed to is not running on localhost?

Comment: Ahhh, you're absolutely right. I was testing it on the server by putting localhost in my browser, but I had whitelisted https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I whitelisted https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/signin-facebook instead, and accessed it from my own PC using that exact url and it works. I was wrongly looking for a setting in my app. Thanks! If you put your comment down as an answer, I'll accept it - cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way owin builds the redirect uri

```
string baseUri =
    Request.Scheme +
    Uri.SchemeDelimiter +
    Request.Host +
    Request.PathBase;

string redirectUri =
    baseUri +
    Options.CallbackPath;
```

where `Options.Callbackpath` defaults to `/signin-facebook`

Since your base uri is reading localhost make sure the server you deployed to isn't running on localhost and you are browsing to it with the correct domain name